# Visual Studio style XML Documentation in XCode?

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, documentation

I've just wasted a better part of 30 mins searching for an answer to the following question:

**Is there any way to quickly generate documentation in XCode for Methods similar to Visual Studio's "///" XML snippet?**

I am aware of Doxygen, but that would still require manually documenting each Method, essentially I'm looking for a way to cut down the work as much as possible.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: How many methods could you have documented by hand in the 30 minutes you just spent looking for a way not to? :)

Comment: Considering it's a job that I have to do day in day out, it's well worth spending the time to research shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this. Doxygen is the closest you'll get - it's what Apple uses. And since XCode 4 kinda forgot automation (applescripting is broke) it won't be coming as an addon any time soon.

[Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) is an external application that helps you through copy & paste code generation. Not nearly as seamless as VS, but better than writing everything by hand. You could customize it's templates to make documentation for your methods.

[TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) is another tool for building text macros. Not as feature rich as Accessorizer, but usable in other applications as well.

Last and probably least, [XCode Snippets can be customized](http://nearthespeedoflight.com/article/xcode_4_code_snippets), but not as much as most developers would like.